# Show list in django without html file?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have 2 models but I want to show the name of the artist in my output

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to show musician name by HttpResponse function

```
class Musician_list(Musician, Album):
   def get(self, request):
       query = Musician.objects.all().values_list("name").order_by("name")
       return HttpResponse(query)
```

but this code doesn't show anything - please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get(self, request):
    names = Musician.objects.values_list("name",flat=True)
    return JsonResponse(names, safe=False)
```

You can read more about `JsonResponse` from the doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

[Your Usecase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#serializing-non-dictionary-objects)